# How I Remove all Div contents but not the div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How I Remove all Div contents  but not the div using jquery?

the div contains many ULs, LIs, DIVs, H1s

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div><h1>test</h1></div>
  <div><h1>test</h1></div>
  <div><h1>test</h1></div>
</div>
```

I would like to remove all the contents of container.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#container").empty();
```

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

`empty` has an advantage over setting the element's html to nothing. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes
>   other constructs such as data and
>   event handlers from the child elements
>   before removing the elements
>   themselves.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').html('');
```